# apt-key deprecated. Install key without installing gpg?

Tags: apt, gnupg, kubernetes

I know that apt-key is deprecated and want to install `kubectl` like this:

```
docker run -it ubuntu:22.04 bash

apt update; apt install gpg curl sudo

curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.

apt update
```

This work (related [Kubernetes issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/41334#issuecomment-1564069335))

BUT: is there a way to accomplish the same without installing `gpg`?

Comment: `apt-key` uses `gpg` internally, so if you were using `apt-key` before, why can't you use `gpg` now?

Comment: @muru using gpg feels a bit strange. I would like to have only few packages on my server. That's why I am asking. Maybe it works somehow without gpg, too.

Comment: It looks like you're also installing sudo for no good reason, so again, why not gpg? And if it's that big of a deal, why not just uninstall it after you're done with it?